# emoji not displaying correctly in VS Code Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, display, emoji

I have a little issue on VS Code. I'm using some emoji which doesn't display correctly on the terminal when usin git bash in VS Code.

A <?> is displaying instead of the emoji. Some of them seem to work...

However, in VS Code if I use PowerShell terminal the emoji are well displayed.

I'm on Windows 11.

I attach a screenshot.

Thanks in advance for your answer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH1Ms.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC7sM.png)

Comment: Its most likely an Encoding Standard conflict. Your terminal probably expects ASCII and your trying to print UTF-16 Standardized double glyph/Quad glyph emojis, or somthing like that.  I can C&P then print emojis in vscode & my terminal in Fedora 35, and I never had to add a special config. Today most stuff is universally compatible. To diagnose the issue, the first thing you need to check, then add to your question (pretty plz) is if you can print emojis in your systems default terminal. Please also include the platform your on, and the type of terminal your using.